# Does tinder make one network request with all swipe data or multiple requests?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, swipe, android-networking

I have a tinder type UI activity which involves swiping left or right of a layout.
Now I need these swipes by the user recorded in the server.

Because making a single network request (using volley/async task) would be too resource consuming so I am thinking of storing the swipe choices locally and then sending them to the server in a single request. So, how do I achieve this? My options as I thought are creating a service in the background (but how would I know when the swipe activity has been finished or paused to make a network request?) or maybe make an async task network request in activity onPause (I have a strong feeling this should not be done, but not sure why).

So my question is how do the achieve the above, and is my design choice of sending them all together in one single request okay, or are there yet better designs?

Comment: I think having a persistent websocket connection might help in your scenario. Is that a viable option for you?

Comment: well the client's backend is in php, so I guess websockets might not be a good option in this case

Comment: In that case you could try Ratchet. If websockets are not ideal then I guess storing the swipes in an SQLite table and sync them to server using  a background service is the way to go

Comment: You could find out by using your PC as a proxy to the device and using Wireshark to sniff the traffic.

Comment: @Kaleb Yeah, I could do that :D But I would prefer SO community's answer as to which is the best method to handle this type of requests